# how to call function inside function in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm developing a shell script to sync the particular folder from target to destination path, I need to execute the script like below:

```bash
sh deploy.sh deploy staging particular_folder_name
```

Below is the script which i developed:

```bash
function deploy() { 
    staging
}

function staging() {
    ENTITY_NAME="$1"
    echo "deployment here"

    ENTITY_PATH=`ls -ld /u01/home/${USER}/testing_vela/subject-areas/entites/staging-modules/${ENTITY_NAME}`
    echo  $ENTITY_PATH

    DEPLOYMENT_FOLDER=`echo $ENTITY_PATH|rev|awk -v FS='/' '{print $1}'|rev`
    echo $DEPLOYMENT_FOLDER
 
    SOURCE_PATH='/u01/home/${USER}/testing_vela/deploy/subject-areas/modules'
    DESTINATION_PATH='/u02/home/${USER}/testing_vela/subject-areas/entites/staging-modules'

    if [ "${ENTITY_NAME}" == "${DEPLOYMENT_FOLDER}" ]
    then 
        echo "folder is exist"
        rsync -avzh ${SOURCE_PATH}/${ENTITY_NAME} ${DESTINATION_PATH}/${ENTITY_NAME}
    else
        echo "folder does not exist"
    fi
}

case $1 in
    deploy) "$@";
    staging) "$@";
esac
```

Can someone help me to correct, if I am doing anything wrong in the above script?
I am facing the below error whenever I execute the script.

**ERROR:**

```
sh deploy.sh deploy staging contract
deploy.sh: line 87: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
deploy.sh: line 87: `staging) "$@";'
```

Comment: Don't use the `.sh` suffix on your shell script: https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/

Comment: "folder does not exist" should probably be considered an error message.  As such, you should write it to stderr: `echo >&2 'folder does not exist'`.  But it seems very strange to emit that error in response to a fragile parsing of `ls`.  If you are going to confirm the existence of a directory, use `test -d`.

Comment: You can use `basename` rather than `rev|awk|rev`.  Also, in awk you can get the last field with `$NF`, so you don't need the `rev`.

Comment: You can also use `${ENTITY_PATH##*/}` to get the last component of the path.

Comment: Sure...I will check those... but the rsync command not able to take folder_name(contract) even am passing while executing the script like below sh -x deploy.sh deploy staging contract

Comment: Variables don't expand in single-quotes, so things like `SOURCE_PATH='/u01/home/${USER}/...'` won't work; use double-quotes instead. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) will spot this and a number of other problems in the script.

Comment: i tried with double quote ,still am facing issue.

Comment: can someone help me to fix the issue...i need to execute the below command successfully
**sh deploy.sh deploy staging contract**  i created "deploy" function and calling the  "staging" function but still am not able to execute the command.

Comment: @rakeshricky At this point, the original problem (the one that caused the syntax error on line 87) has been fixed, and several other problems have been pointed out & fixes recommended, so I'd recommend accepting one of the answers (since they both solve the original problem), fixing everything else pointed out by comments and/or [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/), trying to debug it yourself from there, and if you *still* can't get it working ask a new question (with the new code, error, and probably tracing output from `set -x`).

Comment: Thanks..i fixed the other issue which i faced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for a `case` statement requires 2 semi-colons to terminate the commands of a case:

```
case $1 in
deploy) "$@";;
staging) "$@";;
esac
```

Comment: Now am not getting error ,but rsync is doing for all the folders in target and destination ,but my requirement is should be done only for one folder

Comment: @rakeshricky Parsing `ls` is extremely fragile.  You need to fix the logic around building the `rsync` commands, and verify that they are as you expect and that they are correct.

Comment: Actually ,when i ran the same rsync command on shell not as script,it able to run for particular folder

Answer (score 0):

If it still throws error , put the 2 semi-colons on next line like below :

```
    case $1 in
          deploy) "$@"
    ;;
           staging) "$@"
    ;;
    esac
```

Comment: now am not getting error but the rsync command not able to take folder_name(contract) even am passing while executing the script like below

sh -x deploy.sh deploy staging contract